# WPF Viewmodel update does not update view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, binding

i am working with C# WPF and have the issue that my Model View that lives in another view does now update.

This is my Model Base:

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        InvokeChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected virtual void InvokeChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class Project : ObservableObject
{
    private string _executable;
    private string _name;
    private IEnumerable<ProjectTarget> _targets;
    private ProjectType _type;

    public Project()
    {
        Executable = "";
        Name = "";
        Targets = Array.Empty<ProjectTarget>();
        Type = ProjectType.Unknown;
    }

    public Project(string executable, string name)
    {
        Executable = executable;
        Name = name;
        ReadTargets();
        ReadType();
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetField(ref _name, value);
    }
    //... more in the same manner
}
```

Now i have a view model for `Projects`:

```
public class ShortProjectViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private Project _project;

    public Project Project
    {
        get => _project;
        set
        {
            if(_project != null)
                 _project.PropertyChanged -= InvokeChanged;
            SetField(ref _project, value);
            value.PropertyChanged += InvokeChanged;
        }
    }
    
    //commands and more properties in the same manner

    public ShortProjectViewModel()
    {
        Project = Project.EmptyProject;
    }
    public static Project EmptyProject => new Project()
    {
        Name = "Undefined Project",
        //...
    };
}
```

I want to display (for example) the Name of the `Project` in the `ProjectView` by binding to it like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Project.Name}" Style="{StaticResource DescriptionHeaderLabel}"/>
```

After setting the DataTemplate and DataContext i bind a `ListView` to a List of `ShortProjectViewModels` :

```
//Datatemplate
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ShortProjectViewModel}">
    <view:ShortProjectView/>
</DataTemplate>

//View
<ListView Style="{StaticResource ListView}" ItemsSource="{Binding ShortProjects}"/>

//ViewModel    
private List<ShortProjectViewModel> _shortProjects;

public List<ShortProjectViewModel> ShortProjects
{
    get => _shortProjects;
    set => SetField(ref _shortProjects, value);
}
```

When populating the ShortProjects List the correct amount of views is displayed:

```
var viewModels = projectsToDisplay.Select(x => new ShortProjectViewModel(){Project = x});
ShortProjects = new List<ShortProjectViewModel>(shortProjectModels);
```

The issue is that the view does not update when setting the project to the view model.
[image: Issue Demonstration]
I debugged the project setter and the set project has the correct name and other values but none of them reach the view. I guess some PropertyChanged invocation is wrong but i have now clue what i am missing.

[image: Debugger with correct name]

Comment: Unfortunately your code is not a minimal viable code to reproduce the issue. For example you didn't show how you modify the property and how your DataTemplate looks like. You can check the return value of SetValue to see if it returns false. Maybe your  Equals implementation is erroneous. Why do you re-raise all PropertyChanged events from the Project with the ShortProjectViewModel as sender? It doesn't make much sense as those properties  are not members of the ShortProjectViewModel type.

Comment: For reasons of performance you should avoid to bind Label.Content to type string. Instead use the highly optimized TextBlock and bind to TextBlock.Text.

Comment: How do you set `Project`? Using command, view binding, different thing?

Comment: @BionicCode.
I have not implemented any Equality comparer for my model (neither implicit nor explicit.
I added the data template definition to my post.
I raise these events to try to force the view to update.
Thanks for the performance hint.

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek
I set hte Project property of the view model here:
var viewModels = projectsToDisplay.Select(x => new ShortProjectViewModel(){Project = x});
the 'projectsToDisplay' list comes from a different source that is tested and returns the correct values. Also the shown 3 views are the correct amount and as the debugger shows the correct Project is set. The main question is why the PropertyChanged event does not reach the view. 
ShortProjects = new List<ShortProjectViewModel>(shortProjectModels);

Comment: Thanks for the replies they pointed me to invesigate something. Instead of creating view Models and displaying these, i tried creating the views directly and populated them manually with the view models. Then i started to run into an exception that pointed to the project source. This exception was sucked before in the automatic process of the view creation (i guess). So problem solved